# Pandas - Iterating through rows and filling values based on the row before

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I have a data set with a column labeled 'flag' that currently has values 1, 0, or NA.
I would like to iterate through the rows that contain NA in the 'flag' column and fill them with the value found in the same column but the row above.

`tw['flag']` column looks like `[1: NA: NA: NA:....1:NA:NA:....0:NA:NA...]`

I have tried

```
for i in range (1,len(tw)):
  tw.loc[tw['flag']=='NA','flag'=tw.loc[tw[i-1,'flag']]

tw.head()
```

For this I get a `'key error' (0, 'flag')`.

Comment: Do you want `tw['flag'] = tw['flag'].ffill()` ?

Comment: I'm not sure about ffill()...I want the flag column to contain the value in the previous row of the flag column if the value of the flag column is NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for ind in range(1, len(df)):
    if np.isnan(df.iloc[ind]["flag"]):
        df.iloc[ind]["flag"] = df.iloc[ind-1]["flag"]
```

where `df` is your DataFrame.

*Update*

As @AndrejKesely mentioned in the comment section, you can use built-in `pd.DataFrame.ffil` method:

```
df["flag"] = df["flag"].ffill()
```

Comment: Perhaps I am explaining my question poorly.  If the entries in 'flag' are currently [0 - NA-NA-1-NA-NA-0-NA] I would like them to become [0-0-0-1-1-1-0-0].

Comment: @JosephMellor, Isn't my solution doing exactly the same? if the case is that you have string `"NA"` instead of `None`, you can just replace `if np.isnan(df.iloc[ind]["flag"])` with `if df.iloc[ind]["flag"] == "Na"`.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems to work fine this way.  I am now attempting to run it on the whole df which has 5,000,000 rows.

Comment: @JosephMellor, If your problem was resolved by any of those answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As has been commented by @AndrejKesely before, Pandas [ffill()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) does what you need.

However, it forward fills pd.NA or NaN values, but you have a string. So you simply replace your 'NA' strings with pd.NA:

```
# Replace 'NA' with pd.NA, as it enables things like ffill()
tw["flag"] = tw["flag"].replace("NA", pd.NA)
```

Then you forward fill, as others suggested:

```
tw["flag"] = tw["flag"].ffill()
```

Gives you exactly the result you were looking for (make sure the DataFrame is sorted the way you want it).

This is generally preferable to any kind of loop, because these vectorized functions are typically orders of magnitude faster and also more concise and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If your column 'flag' does not have two consecutive 'NA' you can do this using :

```
df.loc[df['flag'].isna(), 'flag'] = df['flag'].shift()
```

The 'shift' method offset your Serie by 1 so if df['flag'] look like :

```
df['flag']
    0       1
    1    <NA>
    2       0
    3       0
    4    <NA>
```

Then after calling the method shift each row will contain the value of the previous one.

```
df['flag'].shift()
0    None
1       1
2    <NA>
3       0
4       0
```

With the 'loc' method you can replace only a part of the value of your column, in this case, you will replace the values in the rows where *df['flag'].isna()* by the corresponding values in *'df['flag'].shift()'*, aka the one of the previous row.

If you have multiple 'NA' in a row you can continue doing that as long as you have 'na' values, with the folowing :

```
while df['flag'].isna().any():
    df.loc[df['flag'].isna(), 'flag'] = df['flag'].shift()
```

Of course if you have a large number of consecutive 'NA' this might be a bit inneficient and you might want to manually iterate over your serie.
One way to do this would be :

```
memory = pd.NA
output = []
for x in df['flag']:
    if isinstance(x, pd._libs.missing.NAType): # if x is pd.NA
        output.append(memory)
    elif x != x :
        output.append(memory) # if x is np.nan
    else:
        memory = x
        output.append(x)
df['flag'] = pd.Series(output)
```

Comment: I should mentiond that the "NA" I am referencing are manually entered, not the default Nan in python/Pandas.